# What is wrong with my Python code for Leetcode Problem#315

Tags: python

I solved a problem in Leetcode. It passed 14 tests of 16. But then occured an error. I could not find where i made a mistake. Thank you!

PROBLEM: You are given an integer array nums and you have to return a new counts array. The counts array has the property where counts[i] is the number of smaller elements to the right of nums[i].

Example:

```
Input: [5,2,6,1]
Output: [2,1,1,0]
```

My answer:

```
class Solution:
    def countSmaller(self, nums):

        new_list=[]

        for i in nums:
            count=0
            a=nums.index(i)
            my_list1=nums[a+1:]

            for x in my_list1:
                if x<i:
                    count+=1
            new_list.append(count)
        return new_list
```

Comment: The error is. . .?

Comment: what was the test case that failed?

Comment: What if there are duplicates?

Comment: the problem may be that nums.index returns the first match, so if you pass an array like [5, 0, 5, 0], your code will return [2, 0, 2, 0] when [2, 0, 1, 0] would be right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve it for you, one line comprehension:

```
[sum(1 for y in nums[i:] if y < x) for i, x in enumerate(nums)]
#[2, 1, 1, 0]
```